# App Engine - Is the memcache shared amongst versions of an app?

Tags: google-app-engine, version, memcached

I know the datastore is shared amongst different versions of the same app.  Is the memcache?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"All the versions share the same datastore and memcache".

Source: http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/06/10-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about.html